Expo Go app on IOS: Network failure on axios api calls
I'm using expo go to run my react native app on my iphone. I have a backend service hosted on render that handles my api calls. I'm trying to use axios to make calls to this service. Below I have the custom class I made to handle api calls throughout my app. I am able to sign in and hit some endpoints but some endpoints just say: [AxiosError: Network Error]. When that happens, It doesn't make it to my api, but I am still able to hit that endpoint in postman. It also works if I run the app with the 'open web' option when I start my app.
Expo command:
npx expo start --tunnel

Custom Class:
import axios from 'axios';

class ApiService{

    constructor() {
        this.baseUrl =  process.env.API_URL;
        this.axios = axios.create({
            baseURL: this.baseUrl,
        });
    }

    async call(method, url, data) {
        const headers = {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        };

        try {
            let response = await this.axios({ method, url, data, headers });

            return response.data;
        } catch (err) {
            return err
        }
    }
}

const apiService = new ApiService();

export default apiService;

Example call (ERROR):
const res = (await apiService.call('get', `student/${student_id}/sports`)).data || [];

Example call (SUCCESS):
const res= (await axios.get(process.env.API_URL + `student/${student_id}/sports`, {
    headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
    }
})).data?.data || [];

Package json (packages that are relevent):
"axios": "^1.6.8",
"expo": "~50.0.11",
"react-native": "0.73.6",
"react": "18.2.0",
"react-native-dotenv": "^3.4.11",
"@expo/metro-runtime": "~3.1.3",

It was working about a week ago and since i'm able to hit the endpoint elsewhere, it seems like its not an issue with my urls or my backend. I'm assuming it has to do with something on expo's side of things. I've tried adding appTransportSecurity to my app.json and deleting node modules, making sure that packages are compatible and reinstalling but that hasn't worked.

What is the error/response code of an failing request?

there isn't one

Can you try an older iOS simulator?

Similar issue I had encountered. The problem was that the end point's SSL got expired or got invalid. Another reason for such happening may be because of http in end point. IOS doesn't entertain http, ask backend team to make it https (basically secure the end point).
